# PHP : transform a 2 dimension array into 1 dimension

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any PHP function that can be used in my case ?

Currently I have this array :

```
array( "1" => "22", "2" => "4", "3" => "0" );
```

And I need to keep the values and not the keys :

```
   EDIT (array('votes' => array("22","4","0"));
```

I've seen that there is the `array_values` but it retunrs a 2 dimensional array.

Thanks

Comment: `array_values` most certainly does not return a 2 dimensional array. It's as 1-dimensional as a PHP array gets; that is, it had numeric sequential keys starting at 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a two dimensional array, it's a one dimensional hash/map.  `array_values()` returns a one dimensional array as well, but it's map is 0 => 22, 1 => 4, 3 => 0, etc.  It can be treated like a one dimensional array.

By the way, if you need to ignore the keys for the purposes of iteration, you don't need to use `array_values()` anyway.

```
foreach (array( "1" => "22", "2" => "4", "3" => "0" ) as $_) {
   echo "$_\n";
   //22
   //4
   //0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP arrays are always at least "2d". A key and a value. Even your second "desired" array will still have keys in there. It's impossible to have an array with just keys or just values.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. Here's what i want to output : (array('votes' => array("22","4","0"))

Comment: That's easy enough, you could just do `$myarray['votes'] = array(22, 4, 0);`.